# Is it possible to add AppPart/WebPart in mysite's master page?

Tags: sharepoint-server, mysite, app-part

Is it possible to add an AppPart / a WebPart inside custom mysite's master page(SP2013)?

If yes, then give some reference on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can.

Design Manager > Edit Master Pages > Click your Master Page > Snippets

Select the type of web part from the drop down lists at the top and get the snippet code (do any configuration before you copy the snippet). Paste that code snippet into your Master Page layout where you want it.